# Error with HTTPRequest and DocIO

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to open a Word Document in Xamarin Forms PCL using the following code from Syncfusion example:

```
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using Syncfusion.DocIO;

public void CreateWordDoc()
{
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://valufy.file.core.windows.net/valufyfiles/ValufyReportWordTemplate.docx");
HttpWebResponse response = await (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); <----- FIRST ERROR HERE
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
//Converts it to byte array
byte[] buffer = ReadFully(stream, 32768);
//Stores bytes into the memory stream.
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.Close();
//Creates a new document.
WordDocument document = new WordDocument();
//Opens the template document from the MemoryStream.
document.Open(ms, FormatType.Doc);
//Saves and closes the document
document.Save("Sample.docx", FormatType.Docx); <---- SECOND ERROR HERE
document.Close();
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> 1. ErrorCS1061'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first
>      argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a
>      using directive or an assembly
>      reference?)ValufyC:\Users\sreesun\OneDrive\Projects\2Valufy\2Valufy_2Valufy\Data\Export.cs20Active
> 2. ErrorCS1503Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'ValufyC:\Users\sreesun\OneDrive\Projects\2Valufy\2Valufy_2Valufy\Data\Export.cs48Active

Any suggestions would be helpful.  The GetResponse() method is a public method of HttpWebRequest class and I am not able to figure out why it is erroring out.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:**

'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Suggestion:**
[GetResponse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) is not supported in DocIO PCL versions. So, we recommended you to use [GetResponseAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) to get response from HttpWebRequest.

Note : While trying to get a response using given [URI string](https://valufy.file.core.windows.net/valufyfiles/ValufyReportWordTemplate.docx) , we faced some error due to the invalid URI string. So kindly use proper URI string to create web request and response successively.

We suspect this error is not relevant to DocIO portable libraries.

**Error 2:**

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

**Suggestions:**
In Xamarin platform Essential DocIO does not provide any public API to specify file name directly in the save method. This is the cause for the mentioned issue (“Cannot convert from ‘string’ to ‘System.IO.Stream’)

Alternatively, you may use “Save” method with “Stream” overload to save the Word document.

Please refer our [UG documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/xamarin#save-the-document) to know more about load and save Word document using DocIO portable library in Xamarin platform.